# Returning NULL using WHERE IN

Tags: mysql

I am using this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) as values FROM archive WHERE column2 IN (21, 22)
```

The query returns the values ​​of Column1 from lines whose Column2 has one of the specified values​​.

The problem is that in this case the value 21 is not found in the table. So I need to return a NULL. But the query is only returning the value found.

The query is returning:

```
File 1
```

I expect this:

```
File 1, NULL
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? What you are seeing is the expected behavior of `IN()`. Do you want to _require both_ values `21, 22` instead of match _either_ value (which is what `IN()` does)?

Answer (score 1):

A `right outer join`, `left outer join`, `case` and also `not exists` can also be utilized. Some examples below... (with links to SQL Fiddle working examples).

### Right outer join to temporary table (select # UNION)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL THEN "NULL" ELSE COLUMN1 END)
FROM archive
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT 21 AS id
   UNION SELECT 22 AS id) AS tmp ON tmp.id=archive.column2;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/805e1c/9

### Right outer join to 2nd table

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
  CASE WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL THEN "NULL" ELSE COLUMN1 END)
FROM archive
RIGHT OUTER JOIN temporary tmp ON tmp.id=archive.column2;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36fba/2

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT column2, GROUP_CONCAT(column1) as values FROM archive WHERE column2 IN (21, 22)
       GROUP BY column2;
```

That would produce the results for *21* and *22* on two different *rows*.

Please note that you should provide an `ORDER BY` clause to the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function if you want predictable/reproducible results.

If you really want "in columns", try something *like* that (untested -- sorry):

```
SELECT * FROM 
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) as values FROM archive 
                                             WHERE column2 = 21 GROUP BY column2) AS A
JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) as values FROM archive 
                                             WHERE column2 = 22 GROUP BY column2) AS B;
```