# Using a set in the place of a table (or another elegant solution)

Tags: sql, temporary-objects

I answered a question where I had to generate a temporary `derived table` on the fly (or use an actual table), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890815/1688441 .

Instead of using the following derived table (using select and union):

```
  (SELECT 21 AS id UNION SELECT 22) AS tmp
```

within:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL THEN "NULL" ELSE COLUMN1 END)
FROM archive
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT 21 AS id UNION SELECT 22) AS tmp ON tmp.id=archive.column2;
```

I would much prefer to be able to use something much more elegant such as:

```
  ([[21],[22]]) AS tmp
```

Is there any such notation within any of the SQL databases or any similar features? Is there an easy way to use a `set` in the place of a `table` in `from` (when I say `set` I mean a list of values in 1 dimension) as we use with `IN`.

So, using such a notation a temporary table with 1 int column, and 1 string column having 2 rows would have:

```
([[21,'text here'],[22,'text here2']]) AS tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server allows this syntax:

```
SELECT A, B, C,
 CASE WHEN D < 21 THEN ' 0-20'
      WHEN D < 51 THEN '21-50'
      WHEN D < 101 THEN '51-100'
      ELSE '>101' END AS E
 ,COUNT(*) as "Count"
 FROM  (
    values ('CAR', 1,2,22)
          ,('CAR', 1,2,23)
          ,('BIKE',1,3,2)
)TABLE_X(A,B,C,D)

GROUP BY A, B, C, 
 CASE WHEN D < 21 THEN ' 0-20'
      WHEN D < 51 THEN '21-50'
      WHEN D < 101 THEN '51-100'
      ELSE '>101' END
```

yielding this:

```
A    B           C           E      Count
---- ----------- ----------- ------ -----------
BIKE 1           3            0-20  1
CAR  1           2           21-50  2
```